# Nginx is throwing an 403 Forbidden on Static Files

Tags: python, django, configuration, nginx

I have a django app, python 2.7 with gunicorn and nginx.

Nginx is throwing a `403 Forbidden Error`, if I try to view anything in my `static` folder @:

```
/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/myapp/homelaunch/static
```

**nginx config**(`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp`) contains:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name     *.myapp.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;

        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/myapp/homelaunch/;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/myapp/homelaunch/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

**error.log contains:**

```
2013/11/24 23:00:16 [error] 18243#0: *277 open() "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/myapp/homelaunch/static/img/templated/home/img.png" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: *.myapp.com, request: "GET /static/img/templated/home/img2.png HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.com", referrer: "http://myapp.com/"
```

**access.log contains**

```
xx.xx.xx.xxx - - [24/Nov/2013:23:02:02 +0000] "GET /static/img/templated/base/animg.png HTTP/1.1" 403 141 "http://myapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
xx.xx.xx.xxx - - [24/Nov/2013:23:02:07 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

I tried just viewing say a `.css` file in `/static/` and it throws an error like this in source:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It appears the user nginx is running as (*nginx*?) is missing privileges to read the local file `/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/myapp/homelaunch/static/img/templated/home/img.png`. You probably wanna check file permissions as well as permissions on the directories in the hierarchy.

Comment: I tried doing the sudo chmod 777 -R static   (just to see if it does any difference and it doesnt

Comment: So it is likely the user is missing the right to stat/list one or more directories in the hierarchy. This is may be best solved using group membership, but if you do `chmod a+x` on every directory (home,ubuntu,virtualenv etc) I am guessing it will work. The executable bit on directories controls whether users are allowed to list contents.

Comment: Sadly I did this on static dir, then all the subdir and still getting the same error in error.log and access.log

Comment: It is more likely it is 'missing' +x on /home/ubuntu (so not subdirs, but parent dirs). Which user is nginx running as? A different, more or less dirty fix (depending on setup) may be `gpasswd -a nginx ubuntu` (where *nginx* is the user nginx is running as and *ubuntu* is the user private group of user *ubuntu*).

Comment: how can i determine the user nginx is running as?

Comment: and what is missing??

Comment: `ps -ef | grep nginx` should give a list of running nginx processes. `ps -ef | grep nginx | cut -d' ' -f1` should give you just the user (the leftmost column).

Comment: @bryn that was certainly my issue and that fixed my issue. is this safe to do in production?

Comment: @GovindaDasu The short answer is "probably, yes" (if you mean `chmod a+x`), but you could confine it more by setting `+x` on the directories only for the given user or group...or you could set up a directory structure outside of /home. If the rest of your setup is OK (maybe disable directory listings in nginx where not needed?), `chmod a+x` may be just fine! :)

Comment: Make sure you do that at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 35):

**MacOs El Capitan**: At the top of `nginx.conf` write `user username group_name`

My user name is Kamil so i write:

```
user Kamil staff;
```

(word 'staff' is very important in macOS). This do the trick. After that you don't need to change any permission in your project folder and files.

Comment: Somebody gives this guy an award.

Answer (score 13):

It seems the web server user doesn't have read permissions to the static files.
You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. (easiest, safer) run the nginx as you app user instead of default `nginx` user. To do this, add the following in **nginx.conf**

   ```
   user your_app_user
   ```

   Replace `your_app_user` with appropriate unix username for your app. In this case the `your_app_user` already has necessary permissions to the static content.
2. Another way would be to to grant permissions for the web server user to the static dir.

Answer (score 12):

The best solution in that case would be to add www-data to username group:

`gpasswd -a www-data username`

For your changes to work, restart nginx

`nginx -s reload`

Comment: Just solved my problem ✅✅✅

Answer (score 11):

The minimum fix that worked for me is:

```
sudo chmod -R 664 /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/myapp/homelaunch/static/
sudo chmod -R a+X /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/myapp/homelaunch/static/
```

(BTW, in my case the static folder is called `collected_static`)

Comment: This worked for me. Rest of the settings suggested were already there.

Answer (score 8):

Try specifying a user at the top of your nginx.conf, above the server section.

```
user www-data;
```

Comment: If I do that,a nd then restart nginx it says - unknown directive "user" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp:1

Comment: I did this in nginx.conf, but it didnt fix anything

Comment: After this command I must to re-install nginx ... and run all my services again

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue no long ago. It might be a combination of factors. I found how to fix `403 access denied` by replacing the user in the `nginx.conf` file.

- I deployed my website on an ubuntu server using Digital Ocean.
- I created a new user on my new ubuntu server and give admin priviliges

```sh
    adduser newuser

    usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

- I updated my new server and installed few packages

```sh
    sudo apt update

    sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx curl
```

- I followed all this beautiful instruction on [how to deploy your site on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- Since I changed the user and I ssh into my new server using this new user, I need to replace the user on the `nginx.conf`. By default `nginx.conf` user is `www-data`:

```sh
    user www-data;

    worker_processes auto;

    pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

Then I replaced with my sudo user and solved my problem.

```sh
    user newuser;

    worker_processes auto;

    pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

- Then I restart nginx, gunicorn and postgresql(even if the last one it is not really necessary)

```sh
    sudo systemctl restart nginx 

    sudo systemctl restart gunicorn

    sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

And tada.. :) no more issue.

Comment: thanks for saving my life

Answer (score 2):

**Fix 403 error with Django static files on Ubuntu server.**

1. Run this ->   `gpasswd -a www-data your_proj_username`
2. Reload nginx -> `nginx -s reload`
3. Check chmod for your dirs: `/home`, `/home/proj_dir`, `/home/proj_dir/static`

- Run this - `stat --format '%a' /home` . Result must be 755
- Run this - `stat --format '%a' /home/your_proj_dir/static` . Result must be 755
- Run this - `stat --format '%a' /home/your_proj_dir` . Result must be 750

4. If you have different values you can try to change this:

- `sudo chmod 755 /home`
- `sudo chmod 755 /home/your_proj_dir/static`
- `sudo chmod 750 /home/your_proj_dir`

5. Reload you project-server. This solve all permission errors

Answer (score -7):

After hours upon hours following so many articles, I ran across :
http://nicholasorr.com/blog/2008/07/22/nginx-engine-x-what-a-pain-in-the-bum/

which had a comment to chmod the whole django app dir, so I did:

```
sudo chmod -R myapp
```

This fixed it. Unbelievable!

Thanks to those who offered solutions to fix this.

Comment: chmod 777 -R myapp is worked for me. The above code has syntax error.

Comment: chmod 777 is NOT a solution. You're making your files globally read/write/executable; all of these are potentially bad things. Please read up on file permissions and never, ever suggest this to anyone.