# nginx gives forbidden in some png images

Tags: nginx

I have just installed nginx to serve my website.
When I load the page I am getting

```
403 Forbidden
```

for some images, response Headers have

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

I have checked the mime.types file and I have found a record

```
image/png         png;
```

How can I change the Content-type for those images to png ?

Comment: Check your logfiles, a 403 has nothing to do with a mime type.

Comment: may be caused by privileges, u can try `chmod 644 *.png`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182329/nginx-is-throwing-an-403-forbidden-on-static-files

Comment: This question came up from my google search and `chmod 644 *.png` fixed it for me. Thanks @Fancyoung