# how to solve 403 forbidden error in ngnix

Tags: macos, nginx, server, http-status-code-403, nginx-config

[Im getting 403 forbidden error in ngnix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6T9J.png)
[I just installed ngnix and changed root to a file that I want to be hosted but it's still showing that 403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LNh3.png)

Answer (score 2):

The default nginx user will not have access to the file system under your username. So you will have to give access to those files.

Here is something you can try:

Try adding `user user_name staff;` at the start of nginx.conf file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38122766)

Note: `user_name` in above would be your username that has access to the file directory.